# plot two different list in python for better visibility

Tags: python, matplotlib

This seems to be very simple, but I am new to Python and have searched all over to do this the way I want.

I have two lists that I plotted. List A to be blue and list B to be pink when the are plotted. The code I wrote displays two colors, but it seems like mixed. I want them to be distinguishable, any advice to better plot these?

Input:

```
plt.scatter(listA, listB, c=["pink", "blue"])
plt.ylabel("List B")
plt.xlabel("List A")
```

output:
[Scatter Plot Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpPLC.png)

Comment: A point in the plot consists of an x- and a y- coordinate. The x coordinate is the value from `listA`, the y coordinate is the value from `listB`. Therefore is does not make sense wanting to plot the x coordinates in some color and the y coordinates in some other color. I would suggest you create a [mcve] with some 4 or 5 points and clearly state which color you would like to see on which point in the resulting plot.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are distinct, just plot them separately:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xseries = []
listA = []
listB = []
for i in range(5):
    xseries.append(i)
    listA.append(2 * i + 1)
    listB.append(3 * i - 1)

plt.scatter(xseries, listA, c='pink')
plt.scatter(xseries, listB, c='blue')
plt.show()
```

What you're doing above is using one list for the X axis and the other for Y - you need two series to use two colors...